# Get log from crawler bot in front-end

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, next.js, serverless

I'm developing my website with `next.js`, deploying by `serverless`(vercel). I'm doing hard working to upgrade my website's **SEO** performance

**My Question**

I want to get **crawler bot (googlebot, or etc..) access log** from next.js code or aws-lambda.

[this is the image of log that I want to get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb5uw.png)

**User-agent** and **Date** will be the most important log information.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: for lambda functions cloudwatch would have the crawler bot information.

Comment: @Ali how can I have the crawler bot information in cloudwatch? Thank you! :D

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-request get the user agent data from the request and write to a file if you like

Comment: Ops sorry if it is vercel you can get the user agent from const userAgent = headers['user-agent']; from the request https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body

Comment: @Ali  I tried your advice. But, I could not find where should I change in my next.js code to console.log user-agent. I have .serverless_nextjs/defalut-lambda directory in my project. Thank you for replying! ;D

Comment: @Ali I solved my problems! I was deploying my website with aws cloudFront service. I found that I can store user log in S3 by turn logging on in cloudFront. So, I got query by athena and verified user-agent! God bless for your kindness ;D